# How to set up a simple email subscription?

Tags: email, subscription

I am working on a new Wordpress site, and I want to have a placeholder "under construction" page while I'm setting it up that has a link to subscribe to an email service. The subscription service would be used to tell users that the real website is live.

Here is an image of the placeholder page I made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNx8C.png

How would I set up the email subscription service (what method would be easiest and make the most sense for this purpose)?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of what's easiest to manage, there are several third-party email services which provide plugins for Wordpress or code you can insert directly into your Construction page. I personally prefer Mailchimp, but Constant Contact is another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I would use  Mailchimp plugin too! For one reason: The A/B testing facility is excellent. Basically you can test two titles, & see which has the highest email opening rate & then use that.  You can also segment your email list into interest, location etc. Mailchimp has good documentation & there are lots of tutorials on the internet.